# Display grouping in a Vf page

Tags: visualforce, map

I am looking at a way to display grouping in a Vf page. Grouping i need is something like this below

Project1

- Consultant1

  - Timecard1
  - Timecard2
- Consultant2

  - Timecard1
  - Timecard2

Project2

- Consultant1

  - Timecard1
  - Timecard2
- Consultant2

  - Timecard1
  - Timecard2

What really is the best way to accomplish this? 
Should i have map of maps? The first map holding consultant and list of timecards and the second map holding Project and the firstmap. All the info is got from one object only ie timecard.

Or am i complicating this too much. Is there a easier way of acheieving this design in VF page ?

Comment: Wrapper class ??

Answer (score 2):

Here's the basic outline I would use.

In the controller, use these variable members:

```
// Controller members
public Map<Id,Map<Id,Timecard__c[]>> projects { get; set; }
public Map<Id,SObject> records { get; set; }
```

Then, we load the data with a function (called in constructor is fine):

```
void loadData() {
    projects = new Map<Id,Map<id,Timecard__c[]>>();
    records = new Map<Id,SObject>();
    for(Timecard__c record:[SELECT Id,Consultant__c,Project__c,TimeUsed__c FROM Timecard__c]) {
        if(!projects.containskey(record.project__c)) {
            records.put(record.project__c,null):
            projects.put(record.project__c,new map<id,timecard__c[]>());
        }
        if(!projects.get(record.project__c).containskey(record.consultant__c)) {
            records.put(record.project__c,null);
            projects.get(record.project__c).put(record.consultant__c,new timecard__c[0]);
        }
        projects.get(record.project__c).get(record.consultant__c).add(record);
    }
    records.putAll([SELECT Id,Name FROM Consultant__c WHERE Id IN :records.keyset()]);
    records.putAll([SELECT Id,Name FROM Project__c WHERE Id in :records.keyset()]);
}
```

From here, we can now display our information:

```
<apex:page controller="projectcontroller">
    <ul>
        <apex:repeat value="{!projects}" var="project">
            <li>{!records[project]['name']}<ul>
            <apex:repeat value="{!projects[project]}" var="consultant">
                <li>{!records[consultant]['name']}<ul>
                <apex:repeat value="{!projects[project][consultant]}" var="timecard">
                    <li>{!timecard.TimeUsed__c}</li>
                </apex:repeat>
                </ul></li>
            </apex:repeat>
            </ul></li>
        </apex:repeat>
    </ul>
</apex:page>
```

Feel free to modify as you need to, of course.