# list grouping for display in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I would like to be able to group a custom list that I have built with the help of an inner class.
This list looks like the following array when I send it to json serialize json = json.serialize(eSummary);

```
[
  {
    "TypeName": "Type 1",
    "Times": "9am - 10am",
    "Name": "Event 1",
    "Description": "This is the description for type name: type 1",
    "Id": "a09N0000002R0oeIAC"
  },
  {
    "TypeName": "Type 1",
    "Times": "9am - 5pm",
    "Name": "Event 2",
    "Description": "This is the description for type name: type 1",
    "Id": "a09N0000002R0p4IAC"
  },
  {
    "TypeName": "Type 1",
    "Times": "9am - 5pm",
    "Name": "Event 3",
    "Description": "This is the description for type name: type 1",
    "Id": "a09N0000002R0dpIAC"
  },
  {
    "TypeName": "Type 2",
    "Times": "6:30pm - 9.00pm",
    "Name": "Event 4",    
    "Description": "This is description for the second type of typename",
    "Id": "a09N0000003LxoEIAS"
  }
]
```

I think I will need to group this list by TypeName in order to be able to displayed a VF page like this:

TypeName: Type 1

Description:This is the description for type name: type 1

- Event 1
- Event 2
- Event 3

TypeName: Type 2

Description: This is description for the second type of typename

- Event 4

I found a similar display grouping in the following blog URL: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/03/02/dynamically-group-display-query-results/

I am not sure if I have to modify my list, or if I dont need to modify the list and somehow using the visualforce components I can create this type of grouping

I found this similar question [Display grouping in a Vf page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14897/display-grouping-in-a-vf-page)
however I dont want to modify the construction of my list as I will probably have to change the whole controller, now that the list is formed I prefer maybe to manipulate it to create the grouping, if necessary.

Comment: Hi Manza. I updated your question to properly format the JSON. Here is a link to do that in the future - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code - Other than that, great question providing an example of what you want to do as well as links to research you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write have two [inner classes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex_visualforce_5.htm):

```
public class TypeWrapper{
    public String typeName {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    public List<EventWrapper> eventWrappers {get;set;}
    public TypeWrapper(String typeName, String description, List<EventWrapper> eventWrappers){
        this.typeName = typeName;
        this.description = description;
        this.eventWrappers = eventWrappers;
    }
}

public class EventWrapper{
    public String eventName {get;set;}
    public String times {get;set;}
    public Id eventId {get;set;}
    public EventWrapper(String eventName, String times, Id eventId){
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.times = times;
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }
}
```

These inner classes could live anywhere, but for the sake of simplicity, I'll just throw them on the controller.

```
public MyController{
    private Map<String, TypeWrapper> typeWrapperByTypeName {get;set;}
    public MyController(){
        // I don't know what your object type is, but I am going to assume they are of type Random_Object__c and there is a list of them on randomObjects
        setTypeWrapperByTypeName(randomObjects);
    }

    private void setTypeWrapperByTypeName(List<Random_Object__c> randomObjects){
        typeWrapperByTypeName = new Map<String, TypeWrapper>();
        for(Random_Object__c random:randomObjects){
            if(typeWrapperByTypeName.containsKey(random.TypeName)){
                typeWrapperByTypeName.get(random.TypeName).eventWrappers.add(new EventWrapper(random.Name, random.Times, random.Id));
            }else{
                typeWrapperByTypeName.put(random.TypeName, new TypeWrapper(random.TypeName, random.Description, new List<EventWrapper>());
                typeWrapperByTypeName.get(random.TypeName).eventWrappers.add(new EventWrapper(random.Name, random.Times, random.Id));
            }
        }
    }

    public List<TypeWrapper> getAllTypeWrappers(){
        return typeWrapperByTypeName.values();
    }

    public class TypeWrapper{
        public String typeName {get;set;}
        public String description {get;set;}
        public List<EventWrapper> eventWrappers {get;set;}
        public TypeWrapper(String typeName, String description, List<EventWrapper> eventWrappers){
            this.typeName = typeName;
            this.description = description;
            this.eventWrappers = eventWrappers;
        }
    }

    public class EventWrapper{
        public String eventName {get;set;}
        public String times {get;set;}
        public Id eventId {get;set;}
        public EventWrapper(String eventName, String times, Id eventId){
            this.eventName = eventName;
            this.times = times;
            this.eventId = eventId;
        }
    }
}
```

The general idea above is that you are creating a [Map](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm) on your key, which in this case is your `TypeName`. The reason for this is you only want a single `TypeWrapper` created for each `TypeName`. Once it gets created once, you just add `EventWrapper`s to it until you run through your whole list. This can all be seen in the `setTypeWrapperByTypeName()` method.

When you want to retrieve that [List](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm), simply call the [`values()` method on your Map](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm). This can be seen in the `getAllTypeWrappers()` method. Once you have that set up, it should be as simple as using two [`<apex:repeat>`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_repeat.htm) on your Visualforce page.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!allTypeWrappers}" var="typeWrapper">
    <apex:outputText value="{!typeWrapper.typeName}"/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!typeWrapper.description}"/>
    <ul>
        <apex:repeat value="{!typeWrapper.eventWrappers}" var="eventWrapper">
            <li><apex:outputText value="{!eventWrapper.eventName}"/></li>
        </apex:repeat>
    </ul>
</apex:repeat>
```